# Can I germinate chilli seeds from dried chillies?

Tags: germination, chili

I've got a whole bunch of chilli seeds from a dried chilli pack that I bought. They look golden brown and it seems they have been dried using heat, so I'm not sure if they have any chance of germinating.

Does anyone know if these can germinate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always a chance, but if they have been dried using heat, that chance is small to vanishingly small depending on how hot!  - see [this link](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/germinate-seeds-dried-ghost-peppers-41196.html) - although they are specifying Ghost peppers, the advice would be the same.  [ You might be better off trying dried peppers then dried pepper seeds if you are desperate for a cheap solution ]

FWIW, I am doing a similar experiment with dried (for eating) Goji Berries (like peppers, members of the Nightshade family)- and I can confirm that I've just checked them and it looks like a small percentage of the seeds have just started to germinate.  (I am using a variant on the [Baggie Method](http://faq.gardenweb.com/discussions/2766560/the-baggie-method) with a better and more controlled heat source as its winter and to cold to put on the fridge), and its been about a week - I'd expect peppers to take 2-4 weeks to germinate if kept at 20-24 degrees C.

Answer (score 1):

My wife successfully grows chillies from our cockatoo's bird food. Dried chillies in the food sprouted 100% success rate so far.

She places them in coconut seed propagation disks and they sprout within 4 weeks.